# Connection utilization optimal algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm writing a client library for data exchange with webserver. The webserver is not scalable (has some hard limit for max parallel connections) which is outside of my control. It does send (via response header) max parallel utilization - the maximum throughput it can take before it starts throttling. The setup of a new connection is costly (at the initialization of new connection there is a need of metadata exchange between client and server), so the client library is pooling the connections.

I'm trying to come with an algorithm to grow / shrink the pool size properly. In theory a) no single microservice should hoard traffic just for itself b) if there is low utilization it is ok to add new connections to pool.

So far the naïve algorithm looks like this (pseudo-C#):

```
private DateTimeOffset timeToEvaluate;
// some default increase - like 10 for example
private int minAvailableConnections = DefaultIncrease;
private Random rnd = new Random();
// interval over which server calculates throttling quotas
private readonly TimeSpan ServerThrottlingEvaluationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); 
// set to true when there is ask for connection / but connection is missing in a pool
private bool connectionRefusedDueToMissingSlotInPool = false;  

void AfterEachRequest() 
{
  minAvailableConnections = Math.Min(minAvailableConnections, server.Response.AvailableConnections);

  if (DateTimeOffset.UtcNow >= timeToEvaluate)
  {
    if (minAvailableConnection > 0 && connectionRefusedDueToMissingSlotInPool) 
    {
      pool.AddSlots(minAvaliableConnections)
    }
    else
    {
      pool.Rezise(Math.Min(PoolMinSize, pool.Size / 2));
    }
    
    minAvailableConnections = DefaultIncrease;
    // pseudo-random evaluation between 0.5-1.0 of server throttling quota interval
    timeToEvaluate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow + ((rnd.Next() / 2.0 + 0.5) * ServerThrottlingEvaluationInterval);
    connectionRefusedDueToMissingSlotInPool = false;
  }
}
```

It somehow works / but this looks like a problem that was already sorted before. Is there a canonical algorithm how to handle the growth / shrink of connections in pool for a distributed client.

Comment: HTTP is a connection*less* protocol. No state is preserved from one HTTP request to the next. What can be pooled (and already is pooled) is the TCP connection/Socket. When you use HttpClientFactory, the socket connections are pooled and recycled periodically.

Comment: Are you trying to pool *session* information perhaps, like tokens?